# Getting the users who retweeted a tweet

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I'm using [TwitterOAuth lib](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) to query for tweets and for people who retweeted the tweets.
The first query (get the tweets itself) works like a charm, but the second query (get the people who retweeted each tweet) is always returning `Sorry, that page does not exist, error 34`.

This is how I'm calling the lib:

```
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
return $twitter->get('statuses/retweets/' . $id . '.json', $query);
```

Why is Twitter's API returning this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TwitterOAuth adds the '.json' bit on for you. Try:

```
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
return $twitter->get('statuses/retweets/' . $id, $query);
```